Async request reply pattern in zeromq
I want to create a server that will handle a request / response scheme. The client of that server should be able to send multiple requests at one time (so REQ/REP does not fit). It should be like having a simple grpc server, a client is able send multiple requests and then wait on all responses.
I came into a few options. I saw that router-dealer can replace REP-REQ combo. This simple example I wrote does work. Here the client (dealer) sends 100 requests at the same time. (just as an example, in my real app I recv() one request and send() one response)
router.py
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
port = 6000
socket.bind(f"tcp://*:{port}")
print(f"Listening on port :{port}")


while True:
    for i in range(100):
        client_id = socket.recv()
        msg = socket.recv()
        print("Got ", msg)
        
    socket.send(client_id, zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket.send_string(f"Hello from router. Your message: {msg}")

dealer.py
port = 6000
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.connect(f"tcp://localhost:{port}")

while True:
    for i in range(100):
        socket.send(f"hello from dealer1 {i}".encode())

    time.sleep(1)
    msg = socket.recv()
    print("Got from server=", msg)

In a real app I need to know how to send / recv at the same time with the ROUTER socket.
Say my app receives a message, send it to a background thread, then my app need to somehow send() the response. Not sure how to do that (maybe with poll() ?)
However, In the official guide https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#sockets-and-patterns
I see this example:
import time
import threading
import zmq


def worker_routine(worker_url: str,
                   context: zmq.Context = None):
    """Worker routine"""
    context = context or zmq.Context.instance()

    # Socket to talk to dispatcher
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.connect(worker_url)

    while True:
        string = socket.recv()
        print(f"Received request: [ {string} ]")

        # Do some 'work'
        time.sleep(1)

        # Send reply back to client
        socket.send(b"World")


def main():
    """Server routine"""

    url_worker = "inproc://workers"
    url_client = "tcp://*:5555"

    # Prepare our context and sockets
    context = zmq.Context.instance()

    # Socket to talk to clients
    clients = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    clients.bind(url_client)

    # Socket to talk to workers
    workers = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    workers.bind(url_worker)

    # Launch pool of worker threads
    for i in range(5):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=worker_routine, args=(url_worker,))
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    zmq.proxy(clients, workers)

    # We never get here but clean up anyhow
    clients.close()
    workers.close()
    context.term()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Is the last implementation is more efficient than the other? i.e using one router socket to send / recv (probably with zmq.poll()), or using this pattern. Is there a cost involves with the inproc socket (serialization?), how does it works with zmq.proxy()?

what is a better way of the two to implement client - server like I need?

In the last implementation - can the server recv requests and send responses in parallel?

Performance wise, how the last implementation compares with having pub/sub socket on each side - i.e server will use sub socket to get a request and pub socket to return a response. Client will also have the same pair of sockets. That will require two ports which is less convenient. But this way the server can send / recv in parallel (which I'm not sure is possible with the first implementation).


